# How to make the dock transparent in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, dock

When I log in as a Guest user on Mountain Lion, i get a transparent dock with no background 'surface':
[image: Guest user's dock]

I can seem to find the settings that would make the dock in my own users' desktop look like this. Is it even possible for non-guest users?

Comment: Maybe that look is to show you visually that as a guest you can't make changes to the dock. Interesting, I wish there were a way to get that look, the "surface" is definitely not my thing either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the dock transparent in Mountain Lion type the following two commands in a terminal:

defaults write com.apple.dock hide-mirror -bool yes

killall Dock

Answer (score 1):

You could try a program called [Mirage](http://mac.brothersoft.com/mirage-download.html), which should make the dock transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Mirage (as mentioned by ekaj) is a great solution, but it is no longer being updated and the developer's site has been down for a long time. I wrote an app called [MacUtil](http://russellsayshi.com/MacUtil/home) that gets the job done, look [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=OrYp9T72p0o) for a short video showing it in action.

> MacUtil is a customization application for the Mac. It allow you to make your mac your own, with lots of customization options ranging from two dimensional docks to modifications of CoreOS files.

Comment: Instead of a link to a video can you please add a download link for the software? That would make the answer rather more useful.

Comment: Added the link.